# how to remove lag in setState using callback function in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how to remove lag in setState using callback function in react

tried using callback but still lag state and data in array state cannot be mapped

````
    mapfn(){

            ServerAddr.get(`/dishes/read/meal/category`)
            .then(res => {
              const getmeal6 = res['data']['data'];

              this.setState({ getmeal6 },()=>{
                console.log('log233',this.state.getmeal6);
               });
            });
            console.log('log232',this.state.getmeal6);
            this.state.getmeal6.map((item) => {
              return (
                  this.setState({
                    maparr:[...this.state.maparr,item.id],

                  })

              );

            });
            console.log(this.state.maparr,'val32');
          }```

in log233 the state is proper but in log232 the state lags with 1
````

Comment: Also cannot map item.id as it shows only last value in the array

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: By 'lag', how much are we talking about?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your current code is that both http calls, and calls to `setState` are asynchronous.

```
// this call is asynchronous
ServerAddr.get(`/dishes/read/meal/category`)
    .then(res => {
        const getmeal6 = res['data']['data'];

        // this is also asynchronous
        this.setState({ getmeal6 },()=>{

           });
        });

// this call happens synchronously! It will almost certainly happen before the two
// async calls complete
this.state.getmeal6.map((item) => {
          return (
              this.setState({
                maparr:[...this.state.maparr,item.id],

              })

          );

        });
```

If you want to do something after your http call and the setState are both resolved, you need to either be inside the `then` function of a promise, or in the callback function of `setState`.

So something like this:

```
// this call is asynchronous
ServerAddr.get(`/dishes/read/meal/category`)
    .then(res => {
        const getmeal6 = res['data']['data'];

        // this is also asynchronous
        this.setState({ getmeal6 },()=>{
               // this is where you need to put the 
               // code you want to happen after the http call and setState
           });
        });
```

That said, you need to reconsider what you are trying to do - either by refactoring your state management using something like `Redux`, or by using `async await` in your method, to make your code a little easier to read, or by a totally new approach to the problem at hand.

Comment: I haven't used React in anger since the release of hooks, but I believe that in many scenarios that hooks are a better solution for such issues than Redux. Redux being often overkill.